# How to get setuptools to use a relative path in easy-install.pth when doing "setup.py develop"

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm installing a python egg using setuptools with the "python setup.py develop" command.  It's important that all install paths be relative.  I see that I can do:

```
python setup.py develop --egg-path ../../../../my_directory
```

and the .egg-link file uses that relative path.  However, the path added to easy-install.pth still is an absolute path.  How do I make the path in the easy-install.pth file a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

If your sourcecode is in a subdirectory of the installation directory, it will be made relative automatically.

Why do you need it to be relative, anyway?

Comment: The source is not installed in the site-packages directory (we use setup.py develop), but the site-packages directory and the source both live in a directory that needs to be relocatable.  It's for the Sage (http://sagemath.org) project.  For now, we just use a sed script after installation to make the path in easy-install.pth a relative path.

Comment: I don't understand.  You're using "develop" to install things?  (It's not intended for that.)